# view not recognizing its model after git communication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013

A strange thing is happening with my asp.net-mvc project. I have a perfectly working project but when I do anything git related, my views stop recognizing the @model at the top. The views were created as strongly typed views when I first made them, but when I do a git commit/push/pull using gitbash the views get messed up and have red lines all over the place wherever I use html helpers or @ symbols.

Comment: So the editor is complaining about the types, but are you still able to compile?

Comment: yea I can still compile

Comment: Sounds like your view folder web.config is either not under source control or was corrupted during the push/pulls